# Caracteres no legibles al encriptar un archivo con el algoritmo RC4

Tags: java, java-swing, txt, encriptación

**mucho gusto!!**
Actualmente estoy haciendo un programa en NetBeans 8.1 con Java swing para encriptar y desencriptar utilizando el algoritmo RC4 de encriptación, y desgraciadamente tengo que implementarlo desde cero, sin el uso de librerías de Java. El programa como tal solamente puede encriptar archivos .txt, por lo cual es capaz de tomar la dirección de cualquier archivo txt leer, encriptarlo y por ultimo sobrescribirlo.

El problema esta en que al momento de ejecutar el algoritmo me devuelve todo el texto encriptado como caracteres totalmente ilegibles, los cuales no puedo utilizar para desencriptarlo nuevamente. Un ejemplo de la situación seria:
Deseo ecriptar el siguiente texto de un artivo txt: ***Hola Mundo!!***, y me arroja el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(doy una imagen porque al querer pegar el texto las cajitas de pregunta desaparecen.)

Realmente no tengo ni idea de por que me aparecen esos caracteres, ya que en teoría la implementación del algoritmo RC4 esta bien hecha y de igual forma la conversión de los String a cadenas de bytes para realizar la encriptación. O bueno es creo.

Por lo tanto estaría muy agradecido si pueden ayudarme o guiarme. Cabe mencionar que la implementacion de la funcion de encriptacion del algoritmo RC4 esta en la clase archivo.

Les dejo el codigo completo de la clase archivo y el Jframe Principal.

**Clase Archivo**

```
public class Archivo {

private String ruta;

public Archivo(){
    ruta = "N/D";
}

public Archivo(String ruta){
    this.setRuta(ruta);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return ruta
 */
public String getRuta() {
    return ruta;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param ruta 
 */
public void setRuta(String ruta) {
    this.ruta = ruta;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return String
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String leerArchivo() throws IOException{
    File archivo = new File(this.getRuta());
    FileReader fr = null;
    Scanner sc = null;
    
  
    String registro = "";
    ArrayList <String> registros = new ArrayList<>();
    
    if(!archivo.isFile()){
        throw new IOException("archivo no encontrado");
    }
    
    try{
        fr = new FileReader(archivo);
        sc = new Scanner(fr);
        
    
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            registros.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < registros.size(); i++){
            registro = registro + registros.get(i);
        }
        
        fr.close();
        sc.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        throw e;
    }
    
    return registro;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param registros
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public void escribirArchivo(String[] registros) throws IOException{
    File archivo = new File(this.getRuta());
    
    FileWriter fw = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    
    if(!archivo.isFile()){
        throw new IIOException("El Archivo no Existe");
    }
    
    try{
        fw =  new FileWriter(archivo);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        
        for(String registro: registros){
            pw.println(registro);
        }
        
        fw.close();
        pw.close();
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Archivo Guardado Exitosamente");
    }catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}   

public byte[] cifradoRC4(byte[] clave) throws IOException{
    byte[] textoPlanoBytes = this.leerArchivo().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] textoCifradoBytes = algoritmoRC4(clave, textoPlanoBytes);
    return textoCifradoBytes;
}


public byte[] descifradoRC4(byte[] clave) throws IOException{
    byte[] textoCifradoBytes = this.leerArchivo().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] textoDescifradoBytes = algoritmoRC4(clave, textoCifradoBytes);
    return textoDescifradoBytes;
}

private byte[] algoritmoRC4(byte[] key, byte[] plaintext){
    int[] S = new int[256];
    byte[] ciphertext = new byte[plaintext.length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        S[i] = i;
    }
    
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        j = (j + S[i] + key[i % key.length]) % 256;
        swap(S, i, j);
    }
    
    int i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < plaintext.length; k++) {
        i = (i + 1) % 256;
        j = (j + S[i]) % 256;
        swap(S, i, j);
        
        int keyStreamByte = S[(S[i] + S[j]) % 256];
        ciphertext[k] = (byte) (plaintext[k] ^ keyStreamByte);
    }
    
    return ciphertext;
}


private void swap(int[] S, int i, int j) {
    int temp = S[i];
    S[i] = S[j];
    S[j] = temp;
}
```

**JFrame Principal Completo**

```
public class Pagina_Principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Pagina_Principal
 */
public Pagina_Principal() {
    initComponents();
     
    archivo =  new Archivo();
    
    // Cambia el color del Jframe a Blanco
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
    
    btnCrear.setBackground(new java.awt.Color( 245, 239, 231));
    
  //  btnEjecutarAccion.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 251, 219));
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jFileChooser1 = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
    jSplitPane1 = new javax.swing.JSplitPane();
    RC4 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    Comprimir = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    pnlAcciones = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblNombreArchivo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    rbComprimirArchivo = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    rbDescomprimirArchivo = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jpnRC4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    rbEcriptarArchivo = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    rbDesencriptarArchivo = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    btnEjecutarAccion = new javax.swing.JButton();
    pnlToolBar = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    btnAñadir = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnCrear = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Encripta y Comprime Archivos");
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(660, 660));
    setResizable(false);

    pnlAcciones.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 249, 251));
    pnlAcciones.setName("pnlAcciones");

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Seleccione que desea hacer con el Archivo de Texto:");

    lblNombreArchivo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    lblNombreArchivo.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 51));
    lblNombreArchivo.setText("Archivo sin añadir");
    lblNombreArchivo.setName("lblNombreArchivo"); // NOI18N

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 249, 251));
    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Compresión/Descompresión de Archivo", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic", 1, 12), new java.awt.Color(69, 23, 3))); // NOI18N

    Comprimir.add(rbComprimirArchivo);
    rbComprimirArchivo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    rbComprimirArchivo.setText("Comprimir Archivo");
    rbComprimirArchivo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            rbComprimirArchivoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Comprimir.add(rbDescomprimirArchivo);
    rbDescomprimirArchivo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    rbDescomprimirArchivo.setText("Descomprimir Archivo");
    rbDescomprimirArchivo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            rbDescomprimirArchivoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(25, 25, 25)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(rbDescomprimirArchivo)
                .addComponent(rbComprimirArchivo))
            .addContainerGap(242, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(rbComprimirArchivo)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(rbDescomprimirArchivo)
            .addContainerGap(17, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jpnRC4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 249, 251));
    jpnRC4.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Encriptación/Desencriptación de Archivo con algortimo RC4", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic", 1, 12), new java.awt.Color(69, 23, 3))); // NOI18N

    RC4.add(rbEcriptarArchivo);
    rbEcriptarArchivo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    rbEcriptarArchivo.setText("Encriptar Archivo");
    rbEcriptarArchivo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            rbEcriptarArchivoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    RC4.add(rbDesencriptarArchivo);
    rbDesencriptarArchivo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    rbDesencriptarArchivo.setText("Desencriptar Archivo");
    rbDesencriptarArchivo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            rbDesencriptarArchivoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jpnRC4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jpnRC4);
    jpnRC4.setLayout(jpnRC4Layout);
    jpnRC4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jpnRC4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jpnRC4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(25, 25, 25)
            .addGroup(jpnRC4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(rbDesencriptarArchivo)
                .addComponent(rbEcriptarArchivo))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jpnRC4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jpnRC4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jpnRC4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(rbEcriptarArchivo)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(rbDesencriptarArchivo)
            .addContainerGap(17, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    btnEjecutarAccion.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    btnEjecutarAccion.setText("Ejecutar");
    btnEjecutarAccion.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnEjecutarAccionActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout pnlAccionesLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pnlAcciones);
    pnlAcciones.setLayout(pnlAccionesLayout);
    pnlAccionesLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        pnlAccionesLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(pnlAccionesLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(pnlAccionesLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addGroup(pnlAccionesLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(lblNombreArchivo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                .addComponent(jpnRC4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap(148, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, pnlAccionesLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(btnEjecutarAccion, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 112, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(98, 98, 98))
    );
    pnlAccionesLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        pnlAccionesLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(pnlAccionesLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(lblNombreArchivo)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jpnRC4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 27, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(btnEjecutarAccion, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(24, 24, 24))
    );

    pnlToolBar.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(226, 226, 226));
    pnlToolBar.setName("pnlToolBar"); // NOI18N

    btnAñadir.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    btnAñadir.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Icons/abrir-correo-electronico.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnAñadir.setText("Añadir");
    btnAñadir.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    btnAñadir.setName("btnAñadir"); // NOI18N
    btnAñadir.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    btnAñadir.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    btnAñadir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnAñadirActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnCrear.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    btnCrear.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Icons/agregar-archivo.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnCrear.setText("Crear");
    btnCrear.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    btnCrear.setName("btnCrear"); // NOI18N
    btnCrear.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout pnlToolBarLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pnlToolBar);
    pnlToolBar.setLayout(pnlToolBarLayout);
    pnlToolBarLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        pnlToolBarLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(pnlToolBarLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addComponent(btnAñadir)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(btnCrear)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    pnlToolBarLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        pnlToolBarLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, pnlToolBarLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(pnlToolBarLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(btnCrear)
                .addComponent(btnAñadir))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(pnlToolBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(25, 25, 25)
            .addComponent(pnlAcciones, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(pnlToolBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addComponent(pnlAcciones, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnAñadirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filtro = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Arhivos de Texto", "txt");
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(filtro);
    
    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(jPanel1);
    
    String rutaArchivo = null;
    String nombreArchivo = null;
    
    if(result == fileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        rutaArchivo = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        nombreArchivo = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
    }
    
    
    if(nombreArchivo != null){
        lblNombreArchivo.setText(nombreArchivo);
        lblNombreArchivo.setForeground(Color.GREEN);       
        
        archivo.setRuta(rutaArchivo);
    }
    
    System.out.println(archivo.getRuta());
    
}                                         

private void btnEjecutarAccionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    
    String clave = "";
      
    if(lblNombreArchivo.getText().equals("Archivo sin añadir")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Archivo de texto no seleccionado", "Archivo no Seleccionado", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }
    
    if(rbEcriptarArchivo.isSelected()){
        clave = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Ingrese una Contraseña");
        try {
            System.out.println(clave);
            byte[] textoCifradoBytes = archivo.cifradoRC4(clave.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            String textoCifrado = new String(textoCifradoBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            System.out.println(textoCifrado);

            String[] arrayTextoCifrado = {textoCifrado};

            archivo.escribirArchivo(arrayTextoCifrado);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Pagina_Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }else if(rbDesencriptarArchivo.isSelected()){
        clave = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Ingrese la contraseña para desencriptar el archivo");
        
        try {
            byte[] textoCifradoBytes = archivo.descifradoRC4(clave.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            String textoDescifrado =  new String(textoCifradoBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            System.out.println(textoDescifrado);

            String[] arrayTextoDescifrado = {textoDescifrado};

            archivo.escribirArchivo(arrayTextoDescifrado);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Pagina_Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}                                                 

private void rbEcriptarArchivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    rbComprimirArchivo.setEnabled(false);
    rbDescomprimirArchivo.setEnabled(false);      
}                                                 

private void rbDesencriptarArchivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    rbComprimirArchivo.setEnabled(false);
    rbDescomprimirArchivo.setEnabled(false); 
}                                                     

private void rbComprimirArchivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    rbEcriptarArchivo.setEnabled(false);
    rbDesencriptarArchivo.setEnabled(false);
}                                                  

private void rbDescomprimirArchivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    rbEcriptarArchivo.setEnabled(false);
    rbDesencriptarArchivo.setEnabled(false);
}                                                     

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Pagina_Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Pagina_Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Pagina_Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Pagina_Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Pagina_Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Pagina_Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Pagina_Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Pagina_Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            new Pagina_Principal().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Inicia el objeto Archivo
Archivo archivo;


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup Comprimir;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup RC4;
private javax.swing.JButton btnAñadir;
private javax.swing.JButton btnCrear;
private javax.swing.JButton btnEjecutarAccion;
private javax.swing.JFileChooser jFileChooser1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JSplitPane jSplitPane1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jpnRC4;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblNombreArchivo;
private javax.swing.JPanel pnlAcciones;
private javax.swing.JPanel pnlToolBar;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton rbComprimirArchivo;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton rbDescomprimirArchivo;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton rbDesencriptarArchivo;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton rbEcriptarArchivo;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Agradeceria mucho el apoyo, estaré pendiente si se necesita mas información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está en las siguientes lineas:

```
String textoCifrado = new String( textoCifradoBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
System.out.println( textoCifrado );
String[] arrayTextoCifrado = { textoCifrado };
archivo.escribirArchivo( arrayTextoCifrado );
```

la primera debería ser:

```
String textoCifrado = new String( textoCifradoBytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 );
```

ya que UTF_8 no incluye todos los símbolos que se requieren aquí.

si quieres verlo en "Hexa":

```
StringBuilder cadena = new StringBuilder();
for( byte bit : textoCifradoBytes ) {
    cadena.append( String.format( "%02X ", bit ));
}
System.out.println( cadena.toString() );
```

Por otro lado, la linea que sigue, mmmmm...

```
String[] arrayTextoCifrado = { textoCifrado };
```

**textoCifrado** es una cadena, por lo que el contenido de **arrayTextoCifrado** es el siguiente:

```
{ ]Õ}û ®C¸ }
```

osea, un array de dimensión "1", no he seguido tu programa, pero me resulta un poco rarín...

Comment: Muchas Gracias por resolver mi problema te lo agradezco mucho @Marce, y si te entiendo que te parezca un programa raro y desorganizado, pero es un proyecto de la facultad y cuando me lo dejaron a ultima hora también quede bastante desconcertado. Pero igual muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Un placer ayudarte ídolo!!!